# Check if Skype username exists

Tags: api, skype

Just wondered if there is any other option to check if Skype username exists since Skype's API limits my requests on:
`https://login.skype.com/json/validator`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not aware of any other option. I have created a small gem in ruby  for checking  existance of skype usernames. But it uses the same url endpoint as you metnioned above.

You can find it here https://github.com/smnplk/skype-check

Comment: Thank you for that, but I assume it won't help me since it uses the same URL, and the skype's API limits my requests.
Thank you anyway once again.

Comment: Np, I haven't used it for large lists of usernames. Maybe I'll add ability to feed it a list of proxy servers through which I can make requests and rotate between them once limit is reached.

Comment: That would be a nice idea.